# combinations/binomial problem

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

```
There are n birds which need to be put back in a cage.
```

In a specific 10 minute period each bird will be put back at some random point in time.

Find a formula for the probability that m animals from n are put back at the same time, where the 'same time' means in the same 1 second interval. The intervals are (0,1),(1,2) etc

My idea. Lets take any particular interval. Then I think it boils down to a binomial situation with n trials and probability of success 1/600.

So for any particular interval, the probability of m from n being in the interval is

$$p_n(m) = \binom{n}{m}\left(\frac{1}{600}\right)^m\left(\frac{599}{600}\right)^{n-m}$$

because there are 600 intervals we should multiply the above by 600.

Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming $p_n(m)$ was supposed to be the probability of putting _exactly_ $m$ birds in the cage during a specific one-minute interval, the formula looks correct. If $m \leq \frac n2,$ however, you need to account for the possibility that a "put back $m$ birds" event might occur two or more times, so the total probability of at least one event is less than $600p_n(m)$.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks. How would I account for that?

Comment: One could determine the maximum number of multiple occurrences from $\frac nm$, rounded down, and then do something with the inclusion-exclusion principle. I think it could be written up with a summation ($\sum$) formula; I don't know if there is a "simplified" form. If "$m$ are put back" meant "at least $m$ are put back" then there would be even more possibilities to consider.